# How to make input tooltip infront of other input?

Tags: internet-explorer, input, tooltip, z-index

I got issue in IE, when clicking in input field tooltip is firing , but in IE part of tooltip is hiding behind next input field. How to fix that ? (z-index is applied already, tooltip is simple div element with display:none, firing on focus input field)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by dynamically adding z-index for IE7, IE7 takes z-index stack backward. For example if less z-index IE7 set blocks as upper layer.